# Using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-pageradapter

I have some confusion when learning swipe views. I don't understand what does the position in getItem(int position) do, what does it refer to? The position in the adapter? The document says getItem(int position) only gets called when the fragment doesn't exist and what does this mean?

I learned how to use ArrayAdapter and we have to pass an array into an ArrayAdapter but why don't we need to pass an array of fragment into FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

And lastly, what I want to do is: I have a ListView containing several items and if I click into it, it would simply show the item name in another activities(which is already done),then I could swipe left and right to view the other items in the list. How could I do that? Do I also need to get the item position in the ListView?

Comment: @i did not understood your requirement.Did you getting any problem with view pager means did not find current active fragment?

Comment: well, similar. I don't quite understand how pageradapter words. How they "adapt" different fragment?

Comment: If you want current fragment reference then go with find by tag

Comment: But as I said, I have a ListView and I want to click one of them then go to an activity containing a viewpager. The first page in the viewpager should show the content of the clicked ListView item. And I could swipe left and right to view other ListView items. How could I do that? If you know, please post it as an answer and having the code is great! thans

Comment: can you post your pager adapter code and how you can set the data to your fragment

Comment: I didn't write any code yet because I don't have idea on how it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my experience the `getItem(int position)` returns what you want it to return. You can see that the **return type** of the method is `Object` so you can send anything from that method. Now if I am not wrong, what your need is on the click of each ListView item, you want to get the text of the the item and `getItem(int position)` is exactly what you need.

Suppose you have an arraylist called `listViewText`. Then you can define the above method as

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return listViewText.get(position);
}
```

and from the calling activity you can invoke it when the item is clicked

```
String listItemText;
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             listItemText=adapter.getItem(position);
        }
    });
```

where adapter is your ListView adapter

**Update**

That was for the ListView adapters. Now regarding your confusion about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, I think what the documentation trying to say is that, in order to reduce the memory consumption as in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` , the adapter uses the `getItem(int position)` method only at the start when there is no state of the fragment is available. It means for the first time the fragment is loaded. Now when the particular fragment is swiped away, the adapter saves the current states of the fragment (contents ,etc) and when later the fragment is swiped in, the adapter will restore the saved states rather than creating new fragment and hence calls the method only one time.

Note that, the adapter may also call the `getItem(int position)` if somehow the states of the particular fragment is lost.

Comment: I want to ask about the getItem() method in pagerfragmentadapter class but no in ListView adapter

Comment: @Cheuck Kwan Lee sorry my mistake. See my updated question about your confusion. Hope that will help you